# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I push this pointer onto a Deque/ArrayList when it clearly isn't Null

Tags: java, recursion, nullpointerexception, depth-first-search

So I am trying to do a simple maze solver (depth first).  I don't want help solving the recursion method, but for some reason this causes a NullPointerException to thorw on the ArrayList's .add of the cell, can anyone help me know why?  (the MazeExample class makes a simple maze of pointers to N S E W, provided by my teacher so we can try to test our code).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MazeSolver solver = new MazeSolver();
    ExampleMaze example = new ExampleMaze();

    System.out.println(solver.stepsToSolveMaze(example.getStart()));    

}
```

that is the main and here is the MazeSolver object (as of right now it only counts the number of moves to the end, one step at a time).

```
public class MazeSolver 
{
private int steps=0;
private ArrayList<MazeCell> visitedCells;
private Deque<MazeCell> breadCrumbs;

public int stepsToSolveMaze(MazeCell cell)
{
    visitedCells.add(cell); //this is where the exception is getting thrown.
    breadCrumbs.push(cell);

    if (cell.isFinish())
    {
        return 1;
    }


    if (cell.east() != null && !visitedCells.contains(cell.east()))
    {
        steps += stepsToSolveMaze(cell.east());
    }
    if (cell.south() != null && !visitedCells.contains(cell.south()))
    {
        steps += stepsToSolveMaze(cell.south());
    }
    if (cell.west() != null && !visitedCells.contains(cell.west()))
    {
        steps += stepsToSolveMaze(cell.west());
    }
    if (cell.north() != null && !visitedCells.contains(cell.north()))
    {
        steps += stepsToSolveMaze(cell.north());
    }
    else
    {
        steps--;
        stepsToSolveMaze(breadCrumbs.pop());            
    }

    return steps;

}
```

Comment: You don't initialize `visitedCells`

Comment: You haven't initialized ArrayList and Deque. You have created only references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing array List.

Add following in stepsToSolveMaze

```
visitedCells = new ArrayList<MazeCell>();
```

and then add elements

Comment: Thanks so much, I feel a little silly now, but now it's time to feel sillier.  After that gets fixed, I have a stack overflow.  here is the error. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.LinkedList$Node.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedList.linkFirst(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedList.addFirst(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedList.push(Unknown Source)
 at MazeSolver.stepsToSolveMaze(MazeSolver.java:16)
 at MazeSolver.stepsToSolveMaze(MazeSolver.java:43
  and about 100 more line 43 errors.  I am working on it now, but I'd appreciate your insight

Comment: OH, i figured it out, I was in a push pop loop, a simple if fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, visitedCells is never set, so when you try to add items to it, it results in a NullPointerException. You need to initialise it before you use it:

```
visitedCells = new ArrayList<MazeCell>();
```

On another point, breadCrumbs will have the same problem, so you should probably initialise that while your at it:

```
breadCrumbs = new Deque<MazeCell>();
```